# How can we access payload value in mule EE jdbc-ee query?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

The issue is with the insert query, there are only two steps 1) select value from table1 2)insert those values in table2.

Here #[map-payload:ID] is working fine in jdbc mule CE but not in jdbc-ee mule EE.

Below is my code,

```
<flow name="allflows_dev_eeFlow">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="3000"/>
        <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database1">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * from table1]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </poll>
    <db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="EBS Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO table2 (ID, Company, Status) VALUES (#[map-payload:ID], #[map-payload:Company], #[map-payload:Status])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
    <logger message="Order1  #[payload[0].ID]  #[map-payload:ID]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `map-payload:`: it's the old and deprecated expression evaluation language. Use MEL instead, ie:

```
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO table2 (ID, Company, Status)
VALUES (#[message.payload[0].ID], #[message.payload[0].Company], #[message.payload[0].Status])]]>
</db:parameterized-query>
```

Comment: I tried, but I can access that in Logger not in query. Let me try one more time and give you an update. Thank you.

Comment: Please find the error messagewWhen I try with #[payload[0].ID]

Comment: ERROR 2015-07-07 19:21:14,331 [[allflows_dev_ee].allflows_dev_eeFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "payload[0].ID" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: Integer
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Comment: Exception stack is:
1. [Error: unexpected token in constructor]
[Near : {... payload[0].ID ....}]
                       ^
[Line: 1, Column: 11] (org.mule.mvel2.CompileException)
  org.mule.mvel2.ast.TypeDescriptor:72 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/mvel2/CompileException.html)
2. Execution of the expression "payload[0].ID" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)

Comment: When I convert #[Integer.perseInt[#payload[0].ID)], got an error saying Message payload is of type LinkedList. Please Advise. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks David, got the solution in your comment in other Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042884/mule-expressionruntimeexception-message-payload-is-of-type-linkedlist